# How can I have a function in haskell return either a boolean or a list of booleans?

Tags: haskell

I have function in haskell (lets call it 'dumb') which calls 3 different functions. These three different functions return different types, for example, a boolean or a list of booleans. How can I define function 'dumb' to either return a boolean or a list of booleans?

```
data Sumtype = givelist Integer | getprod Integer 
prod :: Int -> Int
prod x = x*3

listnums :: Int -> [Int]
listnums x = [1...x]

dumb :: Sumtype -> (what comes here..?)
dumb (givelist x) -> listnums x
dum (getprod x) -> prod x
```

Comment: You should give a concrete example of how you want to use such a function.

Comment: How about this? I hope this clears what my question is.

Comment: The code you edited in is woefully incomplete.

Comment: I have edited my code. I hope this sort of clears out what I intend to do.

Answer (score 6):

You make it return `Either Boolean [Boolean]`. But I'm suspicious about your motives. It sounds like an X/Y problem.

Comment: should the other functions, for example, if dumb calls the add function also be declared to return either Integer type? I just cannot get the dumb function to run by declaring it to return Either Boolean [boolean]

Comment: @Reeshabh [`Either`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Either.html) is a type constructor, not a keyword.

Comment: @Reeshabh The problem you've having is that type checker is giving you an error an you want to just make it shut up, instead of giving deeper thought to why you're getting an error and what you really should do about it. You get type errors for a reason. So what do you want `dumb` to do, what do these three other functions do, and how do you think they'll help you write `dumb`? Those are the questions you need to ask yourself and answer, or if you get stuck, ask here on SO.

Comment: I simply want to know how can I define a function that can return either of the two return types.

Comment: @Reeshabh: You cannot. Haskell functions have *a return type*. However, given two types `a` and `b`, the *type* `Either a b` can be constructed in two ways: `Left :: a -> Either a b` and `Right :: b -> Either a b`. If you then let your function return `Either Bool [Bool]`, you can inspect the returned value and see if it's `Left x` or `Right xs`.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the the Either type, although with it your function will return Either values. It's defined like this:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

When you want to define a function that can return either a Bool or a list of Bools its type should look something like this:

```
dumb :: Either Bool [Bool]
```

In this case 'dumb' will be a function that doesn't take any arguments and return either a Bool or a list of Bools. In the function's body you can return a Bool like this:

```
Left bool
```

Or a list of bools like this:

```
Right [bool]
```

You can see a concrete example here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/More_on_datatypes#More_than_one_type_parameter

All that said though, the reason Sebastian asked you for more details is that Either is rarely used outside of error handling (AFAIK I know anyway). It's possible that in your case you don't really need it at all, but we can't be sure unless you tell us more about the other functions you use in 'dumb' and about your goals.

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you please have a loook at it?

Comment: @Reeshabh I'm not sure what you want to accomplish. Do you want pass a function to 'dumb' and then apply that function to a value?

Comment: @Reeshabh Well, kinda. First of all, the name of data constructors in data declarations have to start with an upper case letter, so the correct definition for Sumtype is:

`data Sumtype = Givelist Integer | Getprod Integer`

Then you can define the function 'dumb' like this:

Comment: Sorry, messed up my previous comment.

So, then you can define the function 'dumb' like this:

`dumb :: Sumtype -> Either Bool [Bool]`
`dumb (Givelist x) = Right (listnums x)`
`dumb (Getprod x) = Left (prod x)`

When you do this though what you're really returning is a value of type 'Either Bool [Bool]'. In Haskell your functions may only have one return type, so when you want to return values of multiple types you have to package them into a single type.

I still don't know why you would want to do this, but there you go.

Comment: @Reeshabh Sorry, forgot that your functions are working with Ints, not Integers. You should match them up with your data declaration for my example to work, otherwise you'll get a type error.

Answer (score 0):

### Unrelated Probems

It appears you are a beginner - welcome to Haskell!  I strongly suggest you read and work through one of the many tutorials as that is more efficient and complete than asking individual questions.

#### Syntax

Let's start with correcting the syntax errors.  Constructors, such as `Givelist` and `Getprod` must start with a capital letter.  The function `dumb` was typo'ed once.  Function definitions use `=` and not `->`.

#### Types

Now we have type errors to address.  The `Sumtype` uses `Integer` and you then switch to using `Int`.  Lets just stick with `Integer` for simplicity.

With these fixes we get:

```
data Sumtype = Givelist Integer | Getprod Integer 

prod :: Integer -> Integer
prod x = x*3

listnums :: Integer -> [Integer]
listnums x = [1...x]

dumb :: Sumtype -> (what comes here..?)
dumb (Givelist x) = listnums x
dumb (Getprod x)  = prod x
```

### The Question

You want to know "what comes here" where 'here' is the result type.  As written, the function is actually invalid.  One definition yields a list of integers, `[Integer]`, while the other yields a single integer `Integer`.  One solution is to use a sum type such as `Either Integer [Integer]` - this is very much like your pre-existing `Sumtype`:

```
dumb :: Sumtype -> Either Integer [Integer]
```

So now we need to return a constructor of `Either` in our function definitions.  You can lookup the documentation or use `:info Either` in `GHCi` to learn the constructors if you don't have them memorized.

```
dumb (Givelist x) = Right (listnums x)
dumb (Getprod x)  = Left (prod x)
```

Notice we had to use `Left` for the second case which returns an `Integer`, because the first type we wrote after `Either` (the left type) is `Integer`.

Comment: If I follow the same method for : Either Integer IO() it gives me an error saying Either applied to too many arguments.

Comment: Because `Either` takes two, not three type variables.  You want: `Either Integer (IO ())`.  Actually, you probably want neither of these - I find it more likely that there are better ways to accomplish whatever you're doing than `Either _ (IO ())`